# Printing generated bitmap in windows 8.1 metro UI

Tags: printing, bitmap, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, windows-8.1

I have researched for hours on the internet.  I have tried to follow as best as I could the samples provided.  I'm sorry, I still can't get it to work.

I humbly ask for any help on this.  I have generated a bitmap from the new render xaml to bitmap class in windows 8.1.  How do I print this bitmap?  Just think of me as a dumb ass.  Is there a simple way to do this?  Could anyone please write out a helper class or something for me to do this?

At this point, I'm desperate to find an answer for this.

Comment: Create your page content xaml with a bitmap in it. Set your bitmap into that page and add it to the document list to print.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved